# Fuzzy-match and extract words repeated across turns in conversation

Tags: r, regex, fuzzy-comparison, approximate

I'm working on speech in conversational speaking turns and want to extract words that are repeated across turns. The task I'm grappling with is to extract words that **inexactly** repeated.

Data:

```
X <- data.frame(
  speaker = c("A","B","A","B"),
  speech = c("i'm gonna take a look you okay with that", 
             "sure looks good we can take a look you go first",
             "okay last time I looked was different i think that is it yeah",
             "yes you're right i think that's it"), stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

I have a `for` loop that successfully extracts **exact** repetitions:

```
# initialize vectors:
pattern1 <- c()
extracted1 <- c()

# run `for` loop:
library(stringr)
for(i in 2:nrow(X)){
  # define each 'speech` element as a pattern for the next `speech` element:
  pattern1[i-1] <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(unlist(str_split(X$speech[i-1], " ")), collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
  # extract all matched words:
  extracted1[i] <- str_extract_all(X$speech[i], pattern1[i-1])
}
# result:
extracted1
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "take" "a"    "look" "you" 

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "i"     "think" "that"  "it"
```

However, **I also want to extract inexact repetitions**. For example, `looks` in row #2 is an inexact repetition of `look` in row #1, `looked` in row #3 fuzzily repeats `looks` in row #2, and `yes` in row #4 is an approximate match of `yeah` in row #3.
I've recently come across `agrep`, which is used for approximate matching, but I don't know how to use it here or whether it's the right way to go at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Note** that the actual data comprises thousands of speaking turns with highly unpredictable content so that it's not possible to define a list of all possible variants beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done really well using a *tidy* approach. The problem you already solved can be done (probably much quicker) using `tidytext`:

```r
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
# transform text into a tidy format
x_tidy <- X %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = "word", input = "speech")

# join data.frame with itself just moved by one id
x_tidy %>% 
  mutate(id_last = id - 1) %>% 
  semi_join(x_tidy, by = c("id_last" = "id", "word" = "word"))
#>     speaker id  word id_last
#> 2.5       B  2  take       1
#> 2.6       B  2     a       1
#> 2.7       B  2  look       1
#> 2.8       B  2   you       1
#> 4.3       B  4     i       3
#> 4.4       B  4 think       3
#> 4.6       B  4    it       3
```

But of course what you want to do is a bit more complex. The example words you highlight are not exactly the same but have a Levenshtein distance of up to 2:

```r
adist(c("look", "looks", "looked"))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    1    2
#> [2,]    1    0    2
#> [3,]    2    2    0
adist(c("yes", "yeah"))
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    0    2
#> [2,]    2    0
```

There is a great package for this following the same tidyverse logic. Unfortunately, the `by` argument in the respective function does not seem to be able to handle two columns (or it applies a fuzzy logic to both columns so 0 and 2 are treated as the same?), so this does not work:

```r
x_tidy %>% 
  mutate(id_last = id - 1) %>% 
  fuzzyjoin::stringdist_semi_join(x_tidy, by = c("word" = "word", "id_last" = "id"), max_dist = 2)
```

However, using a loop we can implement the missing function anyway:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
map_df(unique(x_tidy$id), function(i) {
  current <- x_tidy %>% 
    filter(id == i)
  last <- x_tidy %>% 
    filter(id == i - 1)
  
  current %>%
    fuzzyjoin::stringdist_semi_join(last, by = "word", max_dist = 2)
})
#>      speaker id   word
#> 2.1        B  2  looks
#> 2.2        B  2   good
#> 2.3        B  2     we
#> 2.4        B  2    can
#> 2.5        B  2   take
#> 2.6        B  2      a
#> 2.7        B  2   look
#> 2.8        B  2    you
#> 2.9        B  2     go
#> 3.2        A  3   time
#> 3.3        A  3      i
#> 3.4        A  3 looked
#> 3.5        A  3    was
#> 3.7        A  3      i
#> 3.10       A  3     is
#> 3.11       A  3     it
#> 4          B  4    yes
#> 4.3        B  4      i
#> 4.4        B  4  think
#> 4.5        B  4 that's
#> 4.6        B  4     it
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I'm not sure how ideal the distance is in your case and if you consider the results correct. Alternatively you can try stemming or lemmatization before matching, which might work better. I also wrote a new function for the package implementing a [stringsim_join](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin/pull/74) version, which takes into account the length of the words you are trying to match. But the PR hasn't been approved yet.

Comment: That's really awesome! Great job! One question: if I wanted to filter the repeated words by a vector of stopwords such as `stopwords <- c("i", "you", "a", "that")`, i.e., if I'm not interested in whether or not a set of words are repeated or not, how would I filter them out?

Comment: Using `filter` :D like this: `x_tidy %>% filter(!word %in% stopwords)` before you run `map_df` (less data to process makes it faster)